# In Matlab is there a command equivalent for New File > Function?

Tags: matlab, function

You can use the command:

edit <function_name>

To open the new function editor window, but, I am in school environment and probably due to restrictions on path settings, editing and saving this way, the <function_name> is not recognized.

But, when Home > New > Function is selected from the Toolstrip, or by right clicking on the current Folder Explorer then New > Function, the function is recognized by Matlab.

Otherwise, it throws the error "Undefined function or variable '<function_name>'".

Comment: The file would be created in the current working directory, is writing here possible? Try `fopen example w`

Comment: Either way it is creating the file in the current directory which has read/write access. But, why the difference? Why creating function  by right clicking on Current Folder or by clicking New > Function on the Tool Strip is visible? But, doing edit <function_name> on the command window is not? Another issue I found is that, the function will be available after you exit out of MatLab and open again. Then, the function works fine! Looks like bug with the Matlab. Or it could be some issue with settings, because, we are only allowed to save changes to a particular folder but not to others.